# Is it possible to scrape data from a sublink and go back to the main link using scrapy? Or is there any tool that I can use

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

For Example I will **scrape** a link and will open any other links that is included in it and then **scrape** those links and go back to the main link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send a request back to the page your requests came from, I just don't think that it would make much sense.
Since you could get all the data you need from the main link the first time around, I think it would be better to pass the item you need for the following pages with the [meta attribute of Request](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) or in newer versions of Scrapy with [cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs).

```py
yield Request(
    "http://www.example.com",
    self.callback,
    meta={
        'item': your_item,
        'main_url': response.url
    }
)
```

You could then access the item or main link using the response's meta attribute, work with your old item and then send a request back to the main link and callback with the item.

```py
def callback(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    main_url = response.meta['main_url']
    ...
    yield Request(main_url, self.parse, meta={'item': item})
```

For the next example I will use this item.

```py
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    text = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    author_description = scrapy.Field()
    tags = scrapy.Field()
```

I extended the example from [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests) to follow the about the author link and then yield the item.

```py
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            item = MyItem()
            item['text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').get()
            item['author'] = quote.css('span small::text').get()
            item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall()
            about_page = quote.xpath('.//a[text()="(about)"]/@href').extract_first()
            yield response.follow(
                about_page, 
                self.parse_about_page,
                meta={
                    'item':item, 
                    'main_url': response.url
                }
            )

    def parse_about_page(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['author_description'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="author-description"]').extract_first()
        yield item
        # here you could go back to the main_page 
        # beware, this will only work if you turn off the duplicate filter
        # and then result in an endless loop!
        yield response.follow(
            response.meta['main_url'],
            self.parse,
            meta={'item': item }
        )
```

Comment: Hello! sorry for delay posting some feedback, can you show me more detailed example? I am new with data scrapping as well on scrapy. For now I am just following the basic example on Scrapy site, you can find it on this link https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html I will really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnRayGuerra don't worry about the delay. Is the example I added more helpful to you?

Comment: Yes this is really helpful for me. Thank you so much, you just saved me from getting stuck.

Comment: Very happy that I could help :)

Comment: i tried your solution, but i am facing an issue i.e. only the first item is being scraped in the loop? Is there a way?